# Blue line in the Image Strip not showing

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]

When I click and drag the little arrow; the blue line showing the real lenght of frames dones't appear. It does with all tutos I watched but with me! Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Video Sequence Editor:
View > Show offsets
[image]